# Using Interactive Toast Notifications with a old WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a working program which opens Dialog Boxes(WPF) for User input . 
Now i want to Refactor and use Toast Notifications. The Notifications need to have the ability of Buttons (Pressing yes or no). The new Win10 interactive Toast Notification seemd perfect. 
I got the official tutorial from Windows. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-send-local-toast

Displaying the Toasts works fine but.... The Programm is a in Visual Studio WPF App(.NET Framework) written in C#. 
It won't allow me to override methods in my App.xaml.cs i need like:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
protected override async void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
```

"There is no suitable Method for override"
Simply because there is none ...i think?!

As soon as i tried with a new Project "Blank App univeral Windows" exept from "WPF App .NET Framework" overriting is no problem. Also new created WPF Apps won't let me override.

So my question. What can i do to still use interactive Toasts with my WPF Project? Or is there a alternative way of doing it?

Comment: WPF is not UWP.

Comment: How about the `OnActivated(EventArgs e)` and `OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)` int the `App.xaml.cs`?

Comment: meanwhile i researched a lot and found out: This is not possible. At least i unsterstand the difference of UWP and WPF now. Now i will target a new idea. Launch my UWP Project Code from my old WPF Code. Any experience with that?